# Error: app:mergeClient_flavourDebugResources

Tags: android, jenkins

I am building an adroid project using clean assemble command on Jenkins.

My build is failing each time I run showing this error. Can anyone help me or tell me how can I resolve error related to app: and proguard.
Here is the part of log that shows error.

```
Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
:app:mergeClient_flavourDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeClient_flavourDebugResources'.
> Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be using some resource with unsupported characters in the file name. Check the names of your files in `res` folder of your project.

It can also happen sometimes if you are using 9-patch image in your project.

If you are using 9-patch image in the project then modify that image slightly with 9-patch editor of android studio and then try to build project.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, I have added this two properties in local.properties and it got solved.

android.enableBuildCache=true


android.buildCacheDir C:\\android_build_cache\\